# Changing visibility of JPanels in JFrame not working as intended

Tags: java, swing

I'm having an issue with switching between different JPanels in a JFrame. I am trying to add two different panels to a JFrame that the user can go back and forth between, with `mainPanel` being displayed when the program is run. `mainPanel` was showing correctly until I added `buyPanel` to the frame. Now I'm having issues displaying `mainPanel` again. When I currently run my program, it comes up as blank. The issue seems to be with the last three lines, however I can't figure out what is wrong.

I've included the relevant code below.

```
public class TestClass extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea welcomeText;
    private JComboBox commandsMenu;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel buyPanel;
    private JTextArea buyType;

    public TestClass() {
        super("TestProgram");
        setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        setSize(550, 350);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup elements for main panel (includes commands menu)
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        welcomeText = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        welcomeText.setEditable(false);
        welcomeText.setLineWrap(true);
        welcomeText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        welcomeText.setText(menu());

        commandsMenu = new JComboBox();
        commandsMenu.setEditable(true);
        commandsMenu.setPrototypeDisplayValue("Commands");
        commandsMenu.setSize(50, 50);
        commandsMenu.addItem("Buy");
        commandsMenu.addItem("Quit");

        mainPanel.add(commandsMenu);
        mainPanel.add(welcomeText);
        add(mainPanel);

        // Setup elements for buy panel
        buyPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        buyType = new JTextArea();
        buyType.setText("Type");
        buyType.setEditable(false);

        buyPanel.add(commandsMenu);
        buyPanel.add(buyType);

        add(buyPanel);
        buyPanel.setVisible(false);
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: I came across that earlier, however my friends who are working on the same assignment said that they were able to do it simply by using setVisible() on the panels which is why I tried to go that route. I will try implementing that though, thank you!

Comment: @Jake `CardLayout` is not only the correct approach to your problem, it will also take care of updating the container by triggering a layout and paint pass.  From my perspective, I'd give you more credit (as the instructor) for trying to use `CardLayout` rather then trying to re-invent the wheel, but that's just me